# R Shiny : how to use checkboxGroupInput values for a search in a table?

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I'm a beginner on R and Shiny and I have a little problem.

If you could help please.

For example, I've added the variable `Group` to the data frame "mtcars" in characters format. Now I have 3 groups of cars : `1`, `2` and `3`, depending on the "mpg" level of each car.

I have coded that for ui :

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Example"),
sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Cars", label = "GROUPS",
                              choices = c("Group 1" = "1",
                                          "Group 2" = "2",
                                          "Group 3" = "3")
)),
```

And that for server :

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$textDisplay <- renderText({    

a<-sum(mtcars$Group==input$dynamic)

a    
  })
})
```

It works great when I check only one box, but if I check more than one, the renderText shows only the number of cars of the last group I have checked.
So, how can I get the number of cars of all the checked boxes ?

Sorry for my English.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So great ! It works ! And thank you very much GyD for all these explanations. I understand better now. Have a very good day.

Comment: no problem. If it helped you, you can accept the answer with the check mark, so that other users know that the problem has been solved.

have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the`%in%` operator: `a<-sum(mtcars$Group ℅in℅ input$dynamic)`

## Explanation:

When you use `a == b` R replicates the shorter object multiple times to fit the length of the longer object:

```
a <- 1:6
b <- 1:2
a == b
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# a    1     2     3     4     5     6
# b    1     2     1     2     1     2
```

When the length of the longer object is not the multiple of the shorter object you get the following warning message:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3)
b <- 1:2
a == b
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# a    1     2     2     1     3
# b    1     2     1     2     1
Warning message:
In a == b : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

(Note that the output is not right either)

The %in% operator returns `TRUE` if the first argument matches any of the second element.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3)
b <- 1:2
a %in% b
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# a    1     2     2     1     3
# b   1,2   1,2   1,2   1,2   1,2
```